# Guitarist and Bassist as only Bandmembers - Rhythmsection?

Tags: equipment, percussion, band

We are two individuals, one is playing guitar and sings and the other plays bass. We would like to just cover some rock songs we like and love. However, we do not really want to add another person for percussion to the mix.

How would you approach this? Right now we are thinking about getting some equipment for our feet mainly for the bassist. Another possibility would be to program the drums, but we like that we currently are light on electronic equipment. What would you think is a nice setup for this scenario?

Edit: The guitar is acoustic. We now have a stomp box as equipment. Currently we have John Mayer, Daughters; FOB - Sugar we're going down; Mumford and Sons - Snake Eyes and FF - Everlong in our still very limited set list.

Comment: Is the guitar acoustic, semi-acoustic or solid-bodied?

Comment: [Stomp box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stomp_box)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bass players can be quite percussive in their playing, taking over some of a drummer's role.

However, keeping just as a duo, why not re-hash the numbers you want to play? You certainly won't make a complete job of cover versions that sound like the originals, so think what you could change, so you still have the basic songs, but play them with different arrangements. Maybe even change the feel of some of them. I sometimes play with a guy who does that, and all the stuff goes down well Change a few harmonies, chord progressions, arrangements, etc.

Comment: Sure! The bass can be very percussive. However my skills are not there yet, to get into that. Any tips on how to proceed into this direction as a bassist?

Comment: Get into slapping and popping, and become aware of the many different ways strings can be played to produce different sounds. And I mean more than use a pick or use a finger.

Comment: Slapping can very percussive. I recall reading the creator of slap bass, Larry Graham say he started doing it because of situations where there were no drums. It’s not appropriate for all styles of music though. Another option is “ghost” notes, notes you pluck but mute with the left hand. You can add these in the spaces between the regular notes for a little extra rhythm.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - absolutely. Just watch out for inadvertent harmonics! Muting is king.

Comment: Harmonics can be an issue but usually more with open strings.  Unfortunately we lost one of our fingerstyle mute kings recently, RIP and long live Francis “Rocco” Prestia.

Comment: [Tommy the Cat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMsJlJdWof8). Live. A crappy recording that illustrates how percussive a slapped bass is. You can hear the snare drum and some cymbals, the rest is all the bass.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest and, in my opinion, most *honest* way to play rock songs with only two people is to go for an “unplugged” sound. Acoustic guitar is a much more responsive instrument to dynamic&percussive playing than electric.<sup>†</sup>

E-bass with a clean amp normally fits in just fine in an acoustic sound, so there's no need to get an acoustic bass guitar or double bass and you don't need to use advanced slapping either.

...Though slapping *can* add a great deal of percussive drive, *especially* on double bass...

Of course, an “unplugged” group will never sound anything like an electric rock band, but starting from there you can add anything no trouble – be it foot percussion, a [cajon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caj%C3%B3n), compensating with *voices* – all works and you're much more flexible than if you start with anything pre-programmed.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Strictly speaking it's not so much electric guitars per se that have limited dyn./perc. response, but the standard high-inductance magnetic pickups and particular the amps that are normally used. Special “broadband” electrics like the Parker Fly through a well thought-through effect setup can be *very* dynamic. Still, the good old hollow body of an acoustic guitar is actually amazingly versatile in percussion etc..</sub>

Comment: Thanks, yeah we in fact are mainly using an acoustic guitar and an amplified bass. So we are currently playing around with a stomp box and maybe we get an additional high head, or something other 'clingy'.

Answer (score 4):

**Bassist**

If the bassist sits down then bass drum and hi hat are possible purely with the feet. The simplest rhythm is to alternate them, bom chick bom chick

**Guitar**

If the guitar is acoustic or semi-acoustic then various techniques are possible by  tapping on the soundboard or bridge.

**Beatboxing**

Give the non-singer a mike and add beatbox sounds. Start simple.

Answer (score 2):

My band (link in my bio) plays live with only 3 of us: bass, lead guitar, and vocals/rhythm guitar.

In order to get our sound, our vocalist pre-records all the percussion and synths so they can be played as our backing track directly from a laptop)

Yes, that means there is effort from him up front, but it makes gigging easy (we travel light) and we know exactly how long our songs are so can work to any set length with ease.

It's not heavy on electronic equipment at all - for festivals or support gigs, we travel with our instruments, mic, laptop, pedals and DI boxes - and that's it.

Comment: That's, for sure, an _option_. But I'll be frank and say that any self-respecting band should try to keep the amount of pre-recorded material to the absolute minimum. IMO the whole point of having a band is that there can be spontaneity, interaction, the timing is _not_ fixed, etc...

Comment: @leftaroundabout - sure, but I gigged with even less gear for a while in the mid 80s (it was a fun side project) - me, a Strat, a Rockman & a cassette player. Setlist was fixed, same as it would be with 4 of us. Sure, you can't extend that fun solo (once played a 25-minute version of a dub reggae track because everybody was having so much fun), but such is life.

Comment: Certainly being done even by [famous guitarists(Buckethead youtube link to one of his concerts)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4bply6Ibqw)

Comment: @leftaroundabout - fo some gigs we have had guests in to play those other parts, but even when we don't we are still spontaneous. I probably don't play the same thing twice, ever...

Comment: @mishan I said “the whole point of having **a band**...” – When it's just a soloist playing over backing track it's a different story, then it doesn't even attempt to be a band. And yes, _the soloist_ can still be plenty spontaneous over a fixed backing track. Whereas, as a bassist, I would feel extremely dumb playing live with a prerecorded drum track, since the whole _grooving with the drummer_ aspect doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how firm you are about not adding electronic equipment, the [Beatbuddy](https://singularsound.com/product/beatbuddy/) is probably the simplest solution to your problem.

It's a performance-oriented drum machine with an expandable library of patterns, in guitar-pedal format. No programming needed, just plug it in, pick yer pattern, tap on the footswitch and start playing.